# How to encode URL in C language?

Tags: c, url

I know in Javascript we can use encodeURI(), decodeURI() founded in this page.
[Encoding Decoding URL](http://www.susiro.com/dencoding/url.html)

I was curious about C language, because I'm planing to use it in next project.

Is there a function to encode URL in C language?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library, consider using [`curl_easy_escape()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html).

```
char *curl_easy_escape( CURL * curl , char * string , int length );
```